# Select values for same ID which have more than 60%

Tags: sqlite, select

I want to select IDs where value2 will be more then 60% for example ID 1 -> B = 66% (2/3*100) and write all event for ID 1. Could someone help me?

```
ID  value1  value2
1      A      1
1      B      2
1      B      3
2      A      1
2      B      2
3      A      1
3      B      2
3      C      3
```

Comment: What is your expected output and why do you expect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `group by id, value1` and use `sum()` window function to get the percentage:

```
select id
from (
  select id, 
    1.0 * sum(value1 = 'B') / sum(count(*)) over (partition by id) percent
  from tablename
  group by id, value1
) t
where t.percent > 0.6
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/knHQjCHnxD7KEuFaDLb4SE/2).
Results:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

Comment: Thank you forpas. May I ask you? If I want to write whole rows and change value1 from B to A? And if condition 60% is alright then write all rows for particular ID.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/knHQjCHnxD7KEuFaDLb4SE/1

Comment: this one is much better for me. Last question at least I hope so last. I can't see where can I put value1 in this case B, but in differnet case can be red, blue whatever. I am beginner with SQL

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement then you can post a new question where you will explain what you want.

Comment: it was sub question because this result is not what I want :-( When ID 3 will have on every row value1 A then will be write ID 3 but is wrong. We want only B and that was my main question